# Windows 8 Start Screen Pinning

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I know when I install most legacy installers I seem to get a boat load of shortcuts that I then have to unpin.  However I recently tried using the util:InternetShortcut element and I got the opposite. I had to search the start screen to find the items to pin.  Strangely the Bing1 showed up and I was able to pin it but the Bing2 shortcut did not show up as available. (Edit: Bing2 is showing up now. Weird)

This is kind of a broad question... but what do I need to know here in a Windows 8 world?  I'm working in an enterprise IT environment currently and I'm being asked to come up with a strategy of managing the start screen for users and one of the tools I was researching was MSI based installers.

One of the high level requirements I have is to be able to create shortcuts to websites and configure the icon for the shortcut.  This seems to be supported by .url files but not supported by util:InternetShortcut. (Edit: The shortcut seems to auto-sync with the target webpage.)

```
    <util:InternetShortcut Id="test1" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Bing1" Target="http://www.bing.com" Type="url"/>
    <util:InternetShortcut Id="test2" Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Bing2" Target="http://www.bing.com" Type="link"/>
```

Comment: As a note, Windows 8 is very aggressive about caching pin states so that uninstalling and reinstalling an application will not change the user's start screen. This makes testing initial pin states particularly painful unless you're using a fresh/reverted VM each time.

Comment: This pinning stuff is killing me.  I get that MSFT wants to protect users from ISVs doing funky things to the system but I work in an enterprise IT environment where the expectation is that we can automate the management of the user experience.  Still digging for solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly setting the icon and other pieces of a URL shortcut isn't supported by `InternetShortcut` today. It would be possible but the WiX custom action code just doesn't implement it today. Probably wouldn't take much effort.

As for default pinning, I expect it's a difference between the way the shortcuts are being created in the WiX custom action vs the way the Windows Installer creates shortcuts. The WiX CA is very, very simple and isn't initializing data in the `IPropertyStore` which is probably why it is ignored by the Start Screen. Again, not to hard to implement but not available today.